# com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstname.Text);

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to add data into table,but its not adding.I created conection, it should work.

```
protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=C:\Users\1\Documents\DB.mdf;Integrated Security=True;Connect Timeout=30;User Instance=True");
    conn.Open();
    string insertQuery = "insert INTO Students(Firstname,Secondname,Telephone,IDCity,Dateofbirth,ID) values(@firstName,@secondName,@telephone,@idCity,@dateOfbirth ,@id)";
    SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);  //
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@firstName", firstname.Text);//adding
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@secondName", secondname.Text);//adding
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@telephone", telephone.Text);//adding
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@idCity", idcity.Text);//adding
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateOfbirth", dateofbirth.Text);//adding
    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", id.Text);//

    com.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Response.Write("Registration is successful");

    conn.Close();
}
```

Comment: Add this : `Com.CommandType=CommandType.Text;`

Comment: where i need to add it?

Comment: Try this: `SqlCommand com = new SqlCommand(insertQuery, conn);Com.CommandType=CommandType.Text;`

Comment: What type is "id" in your database?

Comment: type of "id" is varchar(50).

Comment: Do you get any error?

Comment: no just not add new data in table

Comment: add the return of ExecuteNonQuery into a variable and check if the value is 1.
int result = com.ExecuteNonQuery(); The code you wrote should work without problems.

Comment: do you can to write me a code?where i change it?"